# In react native onEndReached trigger is not called in FlatList

Tags: android, windows, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am using react native FlatList Component.In this onEndReached trigger are not been fired....

```
<FlatList
 data={this.state.data}
 keyExtractor={(x, i) => i}
 onEndReached={() => {console.log('fetch more')}}
 onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
 refreshing={false}
/>
```

React Native version: 0.44.0
Platform: Android
Operating System: windows 10

EXACT CODE :

```
<FlatList 
  data={this.props.product} 
  renderItem={({ item }) => 
     ( <ListItem roundAvatar title={${item.name}} avatar=
        {{uri:'item.img_name'}} containerStyle={{ borderBottomWidth: 0 }} 
     />)
   } 
  keyExtractor={item => item.id} 
  ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator} 
  ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader} 
  ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter} 
  refreshing={this.state.refreshing} 
  initialNumToRender={10}
  onRefresh={this.handleMore}
  onEndReachedThreshold={0.3}
  onEndReached={() => this.handleMore()} 
/>

In this code if we put alert in onEndReached trigger then this done three 
times.Alert show three times but if we call handleMore() Method in 
onEndReached Trigger then this is not working method is not call . Please 
Help for solving this issue .Thank you
```

Comment: What container is this being rendered in? Is there something blocking the end from getting within half the visible length of the list or are you able to scroll all the way to the bottom as you expect?

Comment: i m using View component of react-native in it..

Comment: You have to show code from the container of the FlatList i guess